# Разница между компиляцией в Qt Creator и g++

Tags: c++, gcc, qtcreator

Обычно, я программирую в среде Qt Creator (на текущий момент это 4.4.1). Сегодня, я решил выйти за рамки привычной среды и попробовал написать код в Vim (выходить из vim умею очень давно :)), а сборку выполнить через консоль. Но вот с какой особенностью я столкнулся и не могу понять разницу.

Если написать следующий код в Qt, собрать и запустить, то всё будет работать замечательно:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto x = 0;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если этот же код попытаться собрать через команду: `g++ -c *.cpp`, то получаем ошибку:

```
main.cpp:6:10: error: ‘x’ does not name a type
     auto x = 0;
          ^
main.cpp:7:12: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
     cin >> x;
            ^
```

Объясните мне разницу, пожалуйста.

```
gcc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Похоже, что вашему компилятору в командной строке просто не хватает ключика о поддержке стандарта С++11... Вот он и воспринимает `auto` в старом, С++98 стиле.

Comment: Век живи - век учись. Никогда не думал, что нужно указывать поддержку стандарта явно.
g++ -std=c++11 -c *.cpp - работает.

Comment: @Любитель Это потому что у вас компилятор старый. Начиная с gcc 6.1 и выше (текущая версия 7.2) включена поддержка стандартов С++11 и С++14 по умолчанию и там никаких дополнительных флагов указывать не надо.

Comment: @zed Вполне может быть. Я в сусе на стабильном релизе. Туда только критические обновления отправляют

Comment: Вообще-то большую часть параметров сборки необходимо задавать явно. Как минимум, стоит включить генерацию подробной отладочной информации и предупреждения. Так что команда для сборки обычно состоит из пары десятков аргументов. С перечнем поддерживаемых опций можно ознакомиться [на сайте gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто Qt Creator сам добавляет поддержку С++11 строчкой "CONFIG  += c++11" в pro файле. А при вызове руками g++ надо задавать поддержку новых станлартов явно. 
Это -std= ... Смотрите man gсс по части данной опции. Как правило это "c++11" (-std=c++11)